# Как засунуть базу данных MySql в Docker

Tags: mysql, база-данных, docker

Я сделал тестовую базу данных в mysql. Как мне сделать из нее докер контейнер?
Я запустил
`docker run --name forum -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD= -d mysql/mysql-server:8.0`
но не понимаю, каким образом передать сюда свою готовую бд

С БД работаю в MySql Workbench и через консоль.

Answer (score 1):

Просто импортируйте свои данные (из дампа) в БД в контейнере:

1. Создайте БД в вашем контейнере forum:

```
docker exec -it forum -uUSER -pPASSWORD
create database your_db;
```

и импортируйте в нее ваш дамп:

```
docker exec -i forum mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD your_db < /home/user/dump.sql
```